# Git stopped tracking changes

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I am in the working directory and I have created a new branch

```
 git checkout -b someBranch
```

But **after work in some files** the status don't show any change

```
git status 
# On branch someBranch
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Any idea of what is causing this issue?
Any tip to start tracking again?

Comment: How many files did you change? Maybe they were marked by git update-index --assume-unchanged ?

Comment: I have not made `update-index --assume-unchanged` and I have edited a lot...

Comment: @kiril-raychev Solved. I was working over files included in `.gitignore`. This can help someone else anyway. Thanks...

Comment: post it as answer, so it's more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was working over files included in .gitignore